# How to grep for a word taking into account hyphenation?

Tags: grep, latex

For the purpose of building an index I am searching for some words in a bunch of `latex` files. This process is complicated by the fact that `latex` has a discretionary hyphen command `\-`, which indicates to `latex` at which places it can break a word. I want to include it into my search, but so far I have not succeeded in doing so. For example I would need an expression that would match all of

- `pādapracāra`
- `pāda\-pracāra`
- `pā\-da\-pra\-cā\-ra`

or differently hyphenated instances of the same word.

I understand that to match the backslash beginning a latex command one has to type four backslashes, such as `$ grep \\\\mycommand` *tex`.

In `vim` I can search for such an expression via `/pā\(\\-\)*da\(\\-\)*pra\(\\-\)*cāra`, so I thought in grep it would be something like `grep pā\(\\\\-\)\?da *tex` (and so on, but already this one didn't match anything).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can instruct 'grep' to disregard the hyphenation.

How about filtering it first through 'sed' with something like :

```
echo 'pa\\-da\\-pra\\-ca\\-bra' | sed -e s'/\\-//g'
```

And you can do the pattern matching while at it with another expression (as suggested by user *cas*):

```
echo 'pa\\-da\\-pra\\-ca\\-bra' | sed -n -e s'/\\-//g' -e '/pada/p'
```

Comment: That would in practice then mean to first loop through all my files with `sed` removing the hyphenation, saving those to temporary files, and then grepping these temporary files for my words? Interesting idea. I think though that grep can handle optional things by `\?` but I haven't found the correct syntax yet. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that \? could help you, unless you want to include the possible hyphenation _in the search patterns already_, e.g. `echo 'pa\\-da\\-pra\\-ca\\-bra' | grep -E 'pa(\\-)?da'`

Comment: Yes, I was going to include the optional hyphenation commands in the word. In `vim` this works, but with `grep` I haven't gotten it to work yet. See my edit above. I still don't quite understand the role of `echo` in your answer.

Comment: no need for temp files, `sed` can do it all: `sed -r -n -e 's/\\-//g ; /pādapracāra|word2|word3/p`

Comment: Thanks to the hint at `grep`'s -E switch and the single quotation marks I found a solution now. Still I don't quite understand the role of sed in here.

Comment: `sed` can filter out the optional hyphenation from the input and then proceed to match just like grep. That way you can search for words without first having to insert the optional hyphenation into the search pattern, which can be both cumbersome and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

`$ grep -Ei 'pā(\\-)?da(\\-)?pra(\\-)?cā(\\-)?ra' *tex` does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It is not right way to edit laTeX' docs by bash but hereis if you'd like

```
grep -Ee "$(echo "padapracara" | sed "s/\B/(\\\\\\\\-)?/g")"
```